# Variable with predictor name in Predict.rms

Tags: r, regression-strategies, ggplot2

I would like to build regression models for a number of different exposure variables and show the results using `ggplot.Predict` of the `rms` package. While creating regression models automatically works very well, `Predict` does not seem to like a variable as argument (`mod` is the `ols` model):

```
exp.var <- c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3")

for (exp in exp.var) {
   mod <- ols(formula(paste("endpoint ~ ", exp, sep="")), data=data)
   p.mod <- Predict(mod, exp)
}
```

This results in the error message:

```
Error in Predict(mod, exp) : 
  predictors(s) not in model: exp
```

When I use `Predict(mod, exp1)`, it works without any problem.

Is it possible to either:

- pass on a predictor name as variable to `Predict`
- evaluate the variable in a way that `Predict` does not "see" the variable but only the predictor name (`eval` does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Predict(mod, name=exp)`.

Note that pure programming questions are best asked on stackoverflow.com.